# What is the VBA formula to copy and paste the Output from a User Form into multiple rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a User Form in Excel that follows the following VBA code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

If TextBox1.Value = "" Then
    If MsgBox("Form is not complete. Continue?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo) <> vbYes Then
    Exit Sub
    End If
End If

ActiveCell = TextBox1.Value

ActiveCell.Offset(20, 0).Select

Call resetForm

End Sub

Sub resetForm()

TextBox1.Value = ""
UserForm1.TextBox1.SetFocus

End Sub
```

This VBA code provides me the result generated in the User Form in the active cell of the WorkSheet.

I want to copy and paste this result into 18 rows below and then the active cell should be offset to the row below this cell.

The idea being if a User generates another result through the User Form (command button) will copy and paste this result 18 rows below and then the active cell should be offset to the row below this cell.

Comment: Why ActiveCell? Try to avoid that *always*.  Should it go in the next open row of column A and the following 18 rows (for a total of 19 cells)?  If so, this should work instead of the ActiveCell lines: `ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(19).Value = TextBox1.Value`

Comment: This part of the code: `ActiveCell = TextBox1.Value`resets the activecell, so every itteration you end up there. Also please read on how to avoid select, as that is bad coding practice and is probably the solution in your case.

Comment: The reason for Active Cell is because I wrote out 475 rows of data, as this was Data that is known to us. The Output regarding the UserForm is for new information that Users may implement, therefore I thought it would be best to lock the Active Cell at the 476th row of data and then execute this logic. I hope that makes sense, thanks very much for the help

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Const NumberOfRows = 18
' ...
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(NumberOfRows - 1, 0)) = TextBox1.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(NumberOfRows, 0).Activate
```

Comment: Yes that works thanks very much, I may contact you for more help whilst I am completing this project thanks very much.

Comment: Thanks very much @FunThomas I was wondering whether I could have some more assistance, I now require these rows to be accompanied by columns of data the dataset range = D13:J31. Therefore I would like this this function to continue entering the 19 rows and then enter the data from D13:J31 to accompany it.

Answer (score 0):

After `ActiveCell = TextBox1.Value` write:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(18, 0) = ActiveCell
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
```

The first line generates value 18 rows below the active cell and the second line moves the activecell with one row, thus exactly *I want to copy and paste this result into 18 rows below and then the active cell should be offset to the row below this cell.*

Comment: Did you test this?  I don't think it will do what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @tigeravatar - this does exactly "I want to copy and paste this result into 18 rows below and then the active cell should be offset to the row below this cell."

Comment: You should test it, it will not do that.  It will copy the active cell to a cell 18 rows below (and *only* to that cell) and then select the cell below the *original* active cell, not the one at the bottom.  Please test.

Comment: Though I suppose it could be interpreted that your solution is the intent due to the vagueness of the wording.  If so, I will delete my comments.

Comment: @tigeravatar you are correct that is what I would like. The Output copy and pasted into each of the 19 rows including the active cell and then the active cell offset to the cell below

Comment: so that this process can occur again, should it look like this: Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

If TextBox1.Value = "" Then
    If MsgBox("Form is not complete. Do you want to continue?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo) <> vbYes Then
    Exit Sub
    End If
End If

ActiveCell = TextBox1.Value
        
ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(19).Value = TextBox1.Value

Call resetForm

End Sub

Sub resetForm()

TextBox1.Value = ""
UserForm1.TextBox1.SetFocus

End Sub

Comment: @tigeravatar - yup, it copies the 1 cell to a cell, which is 18 rows below. Exactly the way I understand it. :)

Comment: @Vityata heya I am looking for something where 1 cell is copied to each of the 18 rows below and then the active cell is offset to the one below